# What does the range of convergence in Maclaurin series mean?

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I tried to calculate the following Maclaurin series:

$$
f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2} = 1+\frac{x}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n}(1)(3)...(2n-3)}{2^n n!}
$$

With Ratio Test, I found the range of convergence is $x\in(-1,1)$:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{x^{2(n+1)}(1)(3)...(2n-3)(2n-1)}{2^{n+1} (n+1)!} \frac{2^{n}n!}{
x^{2n}(1)(3)...(2n-3)}| = \lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{x^2 (2n-1)}{2(n+1)}| = x^2(<1)
$$

To me, it means that The Maclaurin series only converge to a solution (and thus only valid) when $x\in(-1,1)$. However, since the $x$ in the original function $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$ can take on any value ($x\in\mathbb{R}$), the Maclauin series cannot give us a solution when $x \leq -1$ or $x \geq 1$. This is the case **even though** the original function $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ can take on these values. Is my interpretation correct?

Edit: Let's limit our discussion to $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Thanks!

Comment: The function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, but you only have convergence (in the very strong sense of power series) on $(-1,1)$. This comes from the fact that your actually have this strong convergence on the open disc in $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. on the disc $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$. It cannot be more, since you start to have an issue around $i$...

Comment: Another reason is that if you let $x$ be complex the function has some 'nasty' (branch) points at $x=\pm i$

Comment: Okay. Assume that we are only talking about $\mathbb{R}$, is my interpretation correct? (I have not got into $\mathbb{C}$ yet.)

Comment: Yes, it is correct. (Not that is *may* give you something at $\pm 1$, even though you'd have to check "by hand.") The approximation of the function by this specific series is not valid outside $(-1,1)$ -- the function still lives there, but the series expansion does not.

Comment: Thanks. The endpoints needs to be checked.

Comment: $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ would be an analytic continuation of the Taylor series. But this does not change the convergence radius $r$ which is the same for real or complex arguments (it converges for all $|x|<r$ and convergence is limited by branch points or singularities)

Comment: I always found it strange WHEN the original function $f(x)$ can allow a wider range of value in $x$ than the Taylor or Maclaurin series. It seems to me that Taylor or Maclaurin series are not 'perfect' representation of the original function. But you guys have better ideas.

Comment: The series' radius of convergence does not discriminate between complex and real values, for a start... so anything it guarantees must hold when extended to $\mathbb{C}$ (even if you don't care about or don't consider it). But yes, it can be counter-intuitive...

Comment: This has been a hard question for quite some time. The book [Visual Complex Analysis](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Visual_Complex_Analysis.html?id=ogz5FjmiqlQC&redir_esc=y) by Tristan Needham refers to it as "The Mystery of Real Power Series".

Answer (score 1):

The analysis is correct.  The function $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ has the series representation

$$\sqrt{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{n}x^{2k} \tag 1$$

that is valid for $|x|\le 1$ where

$$\binom{1/2}{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n)!}{(n!)^2\,4^n\,(2n-1)}$$

The series in $(1)$ diverges for $|x|>1$.

---

Note that we can develop quite easily a series representation that is valid for $|x|\ge 1$ by writing $\sqrt{1+x^2}=|x|\sqrt{1+x^{-2}}$.  Then, we have

$$\sqrt{1+x^2}=|x|\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{n}x^{-2k} \tag 2$$

which is valid for $|x|\ge 1$.  The series in $(2)$ diverges for $|x|<1$.

---

**NOTE: Convergence at the end points**

One way to show that the series in $(1)$ and $(2)$ converge at $|x|=1$ is to use [Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$$

Then, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\binom{1/2}{n}&\sim (-1)^{n-1}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi (2n)}\left(\frac {2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}{(2\pi n)\left(\frac {n}{e}\right)^{2n}4^n(2n-1)}\\\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{\pi n}(2n-1)}
\end{align}$$

And the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{\pi n}(2n-1)}$ converges absolutely.